# Multiple definition error

Tags: mysql, sql, c, netbeans, compiler-errors

I am currently having issues with the SQL Library for C and the linking process.

I am not `#include`ing any .c files, and I do not have more than one function definition for the function names throwing the error. I am only including:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gps.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

According to the internet, I need to add this line to compile the SQL Librarys to the `Compilation Line`:

```
-o gpsComplete main.c -L/usr/include/mysql/ -lmysqlclient -lz
```

This is what shows in the output after I build it:

```
/tmp/ccLqcQ6E.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/main.c:17: first defined here
/tmp/ccLqcQ6E.o: In function `connUploadDataToServerFromMain':

main.c:(.text+0x164): multiple definition of `connUploadDataToServerFromMain'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/main.c:65: first defined here

/tmp/ccLqcQ6E.o: In function `uploadToServer':
main.c:(.text+0x194): multiple definition of `uploadToServer'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/main.c:76: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, when I dont have the line `-o gpsComplete main.c -L/usr/include/mysql/ -lmysqlclient -lz` in, it will fail its build saying the sql commands are undefined:

```
/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/main.c:91: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/main.c:94: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/main.c:96: undefined reference to `mysql_error'
```

So I would say I need the compilation line in there, its just a case of figuring out why it is giving me  the multiple definition error

Comment: Do you have function prototypes of `connUploadDataToServerFromMain` and `uploadToServer` in both your `main.c` file and somewhere else (a header file)? That could cause this error.

Comment: @tonysdg, nope, just in the main.c file. I think I have actually figured this one out. looking at the command `-o` will open the file, so it looks to be opening `main.c` twice, so I removed everything except `lmysqlclient` and it builds. I think this is an error on my part with the `-o` switch.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error on my part.

Looking at the compilation line, the switch `-o` will open the file, which I specify is `main.c`, which is already to be opened, thus calling each function twice.

Removing this line and changing it for `-lmysqlclient` alone fixes this issue should anyone else use the full command as recommended elsewhere.